# Tensorflow contrib.layers compatibility on Windows

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm currently trying to learn more about the layers API of tensorflow, for this I'm trying the cloud-ml samples (census: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/census).

When I launch the script on my Windows computer (Windows-10, run in local, not distributed, CPU mode), I get the following error:

```
   File "\*\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\layers\python\layers\feature_column.py", line 1652, in insert_transformed_feature name="bucketize")
   File "\*\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\layers\python\ops\bucketization_op.py", line 48, in bucketize
      return _bucketization_op.bucketize(input_tensor, boundaries, name=name)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bucketize'
```

In the code of tensorflow (I used version 1.0.0, and upgraded it to 1.0.1 with the same error), I saw in the file `tensorflow\contrib\layers\python\ops\bucketization_op.py` that the op was loaded from native code:

```
_bucketization_op = loader.load_op_library(
    resource_loader.get_path_to_datafile("_bucketization_op.so"))
```

At this point I actually have two questions:

1. Am I wrong to think that this is only valid on Linux, or the `.dll` might have been renamed `.so` to keep a coherent Python code? If there's such a renaming, can someone tell me where I could find this file as a quick search into the folder gave no result for `*.dll` or `*.so` (I assume every native code is wrapped by SWIG inside the `_pywrap_tensorflow.pyd`)?
2. Does anyone have a clue of why this kind of error could happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** These ops should now work in the current nightly build of TensorFlow. I've sent out a [pull request](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/8808) to add support in the upcoming 1.1 release.

The explanation is a bit tortuous, but I'll attempt to lay out the key points.

In general, the `tf.contrib` libraries have limited support on Windows, often because they depend on platform-specific code that does not work (or has not historically worked) on Windows. Until very recently the [`tf.load_op_library()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/load_op_library) API did not work on Windows, but a recent pull request [added support for it](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/8217). Nightly builds for TensorFlow on Windows now include `.dll` files for some extension libraries, and the `loader` library includes code that [converts the `.so` extension to `.dll` on Windows](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/346bd59b3c99055c3fdcbc0d0b0710418f48c5c6/tensorflow/contrib/util/loader.py#L47).

As a historical workaround for this problem, we *statically linked* every `tf.contrib` kernel into `_pywrap_tensorflow.pyd`, and made `loader.load_op_library()` [fail silently](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/346bd59b3c99055c3fdcbc0d0b0710418f48c5c6/tensorflow/contrib/util/loader.py#L49) if the extension was not present on Windows. However, there are two ways to get the generated Python wrapper functions for each op:

- The more common way, which (e.g.) `tf.contrib.tensor_forest` [uses](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/346bd59b3c99055c3fdcbc0d0b0710418f48c5c6/tensorflow/contrib/tensor_forest/python/ops/tensor_forest_ops.py#L22) is to generate the Python source at build time and include the generated code in the PIP package. This works fine on Windows.
- The less common way, which `bucketization_op.py` [uses](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/346bd59b3c99055c3fdcbc0d0b0710418f48c5c6/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/ops/bucketization_op.py#L25) is to generate the Python source at run time, and return a generated Python module from `loader.load_op_library()`. Since we made this fail silently and return `None` on Windows, calling `_bucketization_op.bucketize()` doesn't work.

Finally, due to operational concerns, we determined  that it would be useful to switch between the static and dynamic linking of the `tf.contrib` kernels on all platforms, and the easiest way to do that would be to generate the wrapper code statically. A [recent change](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/b2ac11c0797447eb36d427a0907fb2f05af57fcc) (which alas just missed the branch for the 1.1 release) made the generation of wrapper code consistent across all of the `tf.contrib` libraries.

I hope this makes sense. As a result of all of these changes, if you upgrade to a nightly build of TensorFlow the problem should be fixed, and 
hopefully we can merge the change into the 1.1 release as well!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and this great piece of information!